# Having trouble with DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION setting in jackson views

Tags: java, json, jackson

The official docs on Jackson views at  http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews says that you use this kind of line to exclude properties that are not explicitly mapped to a view.

> objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);

That is what I want to do -- but the line is not compiling for me. Anybody using this config directive?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With the redesigns/refactorings of the 2.0 release, [it got moved](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20#SerializationConfig.Feature.2C_DeserializationConfig.Feature) to [MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION).